# ‘ChaCha’ has not been declared in this scope using Crypto++?

Tags: c++, encryption, crypto++, stream-cipher

I am trying to create a program that run ChaCha encryption. However, I kept getting this problem

> testingchacha.cpp:38:5: error: ‘ChaCha’ has not been declared
>   ChaCha::Encryption enc;

I tried to change the code from

```
ChaCha::Encryption
```

to

```
ChaCha20::Encryption
```

but doing that gave me a long list of error.

I also tried using the example code from Crypto++ website, but I got the same problem regarding 'ChaCha' has not been declared.

```cpp
using namespace CryptoPP;
...

// Encryption object
ChaCha::Encryption enc;    
enc.SetKeyWithIV(key, key.size(), iv, iv.size());
```

Why am I getting the compile error?

Comment: Also see [`ChaCha20`](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/ChaCha20) on the Crypto++ wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an old version of the library.

The name changed from `ChaCha20` to `ChaCha`, see commit [here](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/commit/e2be0cdecce71940682219c067d871c5477a6418#diff-0984eb0851e6ecb84db1cf11faf2a92aL74).

You need at least version 8.1, see also [this issue on github](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues/807#issuecomment-463413636).

Update the library and if you are getting a long list of errors when using the correct name, then you should probably ask about that instead.